# Three.js Change View of Scene by Clicking a Link

Tags: javascript, three.js

Does anyone know how to set up a Three.js scene so I can click a link to change the view of the scene.  I'd think this would be easy to just create a function to change the scene and call the function in a link, but it does not work.

Here is my function:

```
function loadview($x,$y) {

    group.position.x = $x;
    group.position.y = $y;
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

My link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadscene(100,100)">TEST</a>
```

I've also tried:

```
<a href="javascript:loadview(100,100);">TEST</a>
```

When I call the function inside the render function (for testing) the function works:

```
    function render() {

        trackballControls.update(60);

        loadview(100,50);

        // render using requestAnimationFrame
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

If I call the function outside of the render function it does not work:

```
    function render() {

        trackballControls.update(60);

        // render using requestAnimationFrame
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    loadview(100,50);
```

Ultimately what I want to be able to do is click a link to change, not only the object position, but also the camera position.

Here is the test page I'm working on:

http://jay2.ligda.net/3Dtest/stackoverflow1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the parameters.

A simple way to solve this would be

```
<a href="#" id="testButton">TEST</a>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
var testButton = document.getElementById('testButton');
testButton.onclick = function () {
    loadScene(100, 100);
};
```